# Pylabのfigure()が使えなくなりました

Tags: python

pylabでの描写の為に、以下の通り実行すると、モジュールはfigureを使えないと出て参りました。
pylabは、`$pip install --upgrade pylab`にて最新のものを使っています。
`pylab.figure()`だけではなく、`pylab.plot()`、`pylab.show()`等々でも同様のエラーを吐きます。解決策教えていただけましたら助かります。

```
 Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import pylab as pl
    >>> pl.figure()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'figure'
```

pylabは、以下に格納されております。

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

使用されているpylabは以下の通り。

```
>>> import pylab
>>> print(pylab.__file__)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab/__init__.pyc
```

また、pythonはbrewでインストールしたものを使用しています。

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` とするとどうなりますでしょうか？(pylab の実体は matplotlib.pyplot です)

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` でしたら通りました！
`import pylab as pl`だと通りません…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

過去に **`pylab`** と名乗っていたパッケージは [**`scibag`**](https://github.com/javipalanca/scibag) と[改名されました](https://github.com/javipalanca/scibag/issues/1)。
また同名のパッケージが出現しない限り、新たにこの問題が発生する事はありません。
(2016/12/03)

---

#### "pylab"というパッケージが提供する"pylabモジュール"はmatplotlibの"pylabモジュール"とは別の物でした

"pylab"というパッケージは[いろいろなパッケージ](https://github.com/javipalanca/pylab/blob/master/requirements.txt)をインストールするためにある空のパッケージのようです。
質問のように、これを使いインストールすると、ややこしい状況になります。
`pylab`というモジュール名がこの空のモジュールに取られてしまいます。

これは`sudo pip2 uninstall pylab`などとして**削除した方がよい**でしょう。
(何なんでしょうか。**罠としか思えない**)

matplotlibのインストールは`sudo pip2 install matplotlib`で出来ますし、これでmatplotlibが提供するpylabも使えるようになります。

[matplotlibのドキュメント](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related)にpylabは非推奨なので、matplotlib.pyplotを使うように、とありますが、これはこの問題とは関係なかったですね。

> many examples use pylab, it is no longer recommended.

#### importされているpylabがどこのpylabか確認する方法

```python
import pylab
print(pylab.__file__)
```

うっかり作業ディレクトリにpylab.pyというファイルを作ってしまっていた、というようなケースもあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。importしたpylabの場所を追記いたしました。

Comment: @koppepanna 最初、matplotlibが互換性を切り捨てたのかと思いましたが、違いました。状況が分かりましたので、まとめておきます。

Comment: 上記の通りpylab一回アンインストールしてから、pylabを使ってみると、しっかり`>>> pylab.figure()`動きました！！ありがとうございます！